# MySql SP is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am new in mysql I am trying to get data using below SP where I used if else statements

```
CREATE DEFINER=`Travel_user`@`%` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(in bus_id int, in travel_id int, in tr_date Date, in Seat_no varchar(45))

BEGIN

    select  @SeatNo := Fare from Travel_booking.SpecialFares where TravelId=travel_id and date=tr_date ;

IF (@SeatNo = NULL) then

    select @SeatNo := sd.Fare from SeatDetails as sd 
    inner join tbl_ColumnDetails as c on c.ColumnId=sd.ColId 
    inner join tbl_RowsDetails as r on r.RowId=c.RowID 
    inner join BusStructure as bs on bs.StructId=r.StructureId 
    inner join BusDetails as bd on bd.Structure=bs.StructId 
    where sd.IsActive=1 and bd.BusiId=bus_id and sd.travelid=travel_id and sd.SeatNo=Seat_no;

END IF;
END
```

I am calling it like

```
call Travel_booking.new_procedure(34, 53, '2018-03-01', 'L2');
```

First select query is working fine and its showing proper result.
But if statement giving blank result when the result of first query is blank.

I have check both query separately like below they both working.

First query,

```
select Fare from Travel_booking.SpecialFares
where TravelId=53 and date='2018-03-02';
```

Second query,

```
select sd.Fare from SeatDetails as sd
inner join tbl_ColumnDetails as c on c.ColumnId=sd.ColId
inner join BusStructure as bs on bs.StructId=r.StructureId
inner join BusDetails as bd on bd.Structure=bs.StructId
where sd.IsActive=1 and bd.BusiId=34 and sd.travelid=53 and sd.SeatNo='L2';
```

But when I execute them in SP and passing parameters to them so I am getting blank result in if statement in same query.

Comment: `SELECT @SeatN :=. . . ` is incorrectly spelled.

Comment: @Brien sorry it was typing mistake here

Comment: now i corrected it but still getting blank result

Comment: You are using @Seatno in both your queries.

Comment: Read up is null vs = null

Comment: @ks123 No. only in second query

Comment: @P.Salmon I checked it using both 'is null' and '= null'

Comment: Don't use parameter names that are the same as column names.

Comment: @P.Salmon all parameters are different from the column names

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestions would be.

1) You have many `joins` please take a look if each join has any values and if these `joins` are correctly connected, meaning the joins are of equal value.

2) Check your parameters, In you SQL environment,  check if your parameters produces results or not.

3)A tip would also be, check if your parameters is being passed correctly. Creating a output would instantly tell you, the developer of what is wrong with your code.

Comment: my query is correct and working fine but when i pass parameters to it its not working

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for responding and helping me to find out where i am wrong.
I got my answer
Just simply declaring null variable at the start of SP like

```
BEGIN
select  @SeatNo := NULL;
select  @SeatNo := Fare from Travel_booking.SpecialFares where TravelId=travel_id and date=tr_date ;....
```

Comment: As you have discovered, `SELECT ... INTO` [does not do what people commonly expect](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35207/11651)  when no row is found.  You should also look into stored program variables rather than using user-defined variables in procedures.

Answer (score 0):

IF (@SeatNo **is** NULL) then

```
select @SeatNo := sd.Fare from SeatDetails as sd 
inner join tbl_ColumnDetails as c on c.ColumnId=sd.ColId 
inner join tbl_RowsDetails as r on r.RowId=c.RowID 
inner join BusStructure as bs on bs.StructId=r.StructureId 
inner join BusDetails as bd on bd.Structure=bs.StructId 
where sd.IsActive=1 and bd.BusiId=bus_id and sd.travelid=travel_id and sd.SeatNo=Seat_no;
```

END IF;

write is instead of '=';

Comment: i already tried it but its working only until the result of first query is blank. when first query add some value in @SeatNo then i am getting blank result even first query is also blank

Comment: Modify :- IF (@SeatNo is NULL or @SeatNo='') then

Comment: If you want to return value if @SeatNo is null or blank then write else part for new requirements...

Comment: I modified IF expression as you suggest me. Still not working